# Recursion and Arrays - Base Case - Length equals 0 or 1

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, recursion

I read that, in general, the base case for recursive list functions will either be when the length of the array is equal to 0 or 1. Are there scenarios when one base case is a better option than the other?

Comment: there is no _better_ or _worse_ base cases, there are only _necessary_ and _not necessary_  base cases

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the base is independent of the array indices and they depend on the logic.

You can always improve, add and remove unwanted base cases to improve time and space complexity of the solution.